# Does the bitwise OR operator do anything special to a 2's complement byte?

Tags: c++, arduino, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift

So I need to dig a bit into number representation for sensor readout over I2C -- and for the readout of an I2C accelerometer there is one step I just cannot wrap my head around (bold part):

> In order to read them all, we start with the first register, and the using the `requestionFrom()` function we ask to read the 6 registers. Then using the `read()` function, we read the data from each register, **and because the outputs are twos complements we combine them appropriately to get the correct values.**
>
> ```
> // === Read acceleromter data === //
> Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
> Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
> Wire.endTransmission(false);
> Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
> X_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value <--------------
> X_out = X_out/256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
> Y_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
> Y_out = Y_out/256;
> Z_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
> Z_out = Z_out/256;
> ```
>
> https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-track-orientation-with-arduino-and-adxl345-accelerometer/

Here (in Arduino's C++ flavor) we've defined `X_out` as a float, we're reading the two bytes of the X-axis with `Wire.read()` and `Wire.read()` bitshifted 8x to the left (`<--------------` line). But how (or rather why) does the bitwise OR operation merge the information of the two bytes? I can't find any clear answer by googling. Is this something standard I just don't know of?

Comment: don't post image of text. Copy and paste them here

Comment: there are lots of duplicates on this but I don't know which one this should be closed as a dupe

Comment: Its not what you asked about but the order of evaluation is not defined in C++ so that the compiler could evaluate Wire.read() << 8 before Wire.read(). You might get what you want with one set of compiler flags on one version of the compiler, and then get what you don't want if you change either. For example see //en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise OR just means outputting the [inclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) of each bit of the inputs. It has nothing to do with 2's complement

So if we have two bytes X and Y with bit patterns `abcdefgh` and `ABCDEFGH` respectively, the result of `X | Y << 8` is like this

```
Y             00000000ABCDEFGH
Y << 8        ABCDEFGH00000000
X             00000000abcdefgh
──────────────────────────────
X | Y << 8    ABCDEFGHabcdefgh
```

It works because anything OR with 0 is equal to itself. Just look at the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators) and you'll see.So `A OR 0 = A`, `B OR 0 = B`, `0 OR a = a` and so on

In this case `+` and XOR also works because `0 XOR x = x` and `0 + x = x`. So `X + (Y << 8) == X ^ (Y << 8) == X | (Y << 8)`

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I misunderstood what the bit-shifting did in this case; every call of wire.read() reads the next incoming byte, I wrongly thought that the shifting 'read' the next byte.